# A set containing a set as members

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am confuse on a set containing a set is or not a subset of a set.

Like:
$$A=\{1,\{2\},\{3\},4,\{5\}\}$$
$$B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$$

Can I say $A\subseteq B$ ? 
If there is a venn diagram, $\{2\},\{3\},\{5\}$ is an other set?

Or, the member $2,3,5$ of set $B$ is same as the member $\{2\},\{3\},\{5\}$ of set $A$?

Thank you.

Comment: $2 \in B$, i.e. the number $2$ is an *element* of $B$. $\{ 2 \} \in A$ i.e. the *set* $\{ 2 \}$ is an *element* of $A$. But $2 \ne \{ 2 \}$ and $\{ 2 \} \notin B$. Thus, $A \nsubseteq B$.

Comment: $A \not \subset B$.  $\{2\} \in A$ but $\{2\} \not \in B$.  $\{3\} \in A$ but $\{3\} \not \in B$.  And $\{5\}\in A$ but $\{5\} \not \in B$.  So $A$ can not be a subset of $B$.  Now $2\in B$ and $3 \in B$ and $5\in B$ but $2\ne \{2\}$ and $3\ne \{3\}$ and $5\ne \{5\}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: So to be a subset, a set containing a set as members, other set should be a set containing a set as members too, otherwise they are not the same. is it right?

Comment: The comments and answers here notwithstanding it should be noted that some authors explicitly identify objects $a$ with the singleton set $\{a\}$. This simplifies somewhat the definition of an inverse function if it exists. I suggest using the "unpack operator" ${\rm the}\bigl(\{a\}\bigr):=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{2\} \ne 2$ and $\{3\} \ne 3$ and $\{5\} \ne 5$.

If you were to make a Venn Diagram of these to sets you will see:

$A \cup B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\{2\},\{3\},\{5\}\}$

$A \cap B = \{1,4\}$

$A \setminus B =\{\{2\},\{3\},\{5\}\}$

And $B\setminus A = \{2,3,5,6,7\}$

And $[B\setminus A]\cap [A\setminus B] = \{2,3,5,6,7\}\cap \{\{2\},\{3\},\{5\}\} = \emptyset$.

So, no, $A \not \subset B$.